# tab indicator not moving when swiping but moves on selection

Tags: android, indicator

I have a main activity with 3 tabs,when i swipe the tabbed indicator doesn't move but the layout changes while selecting a tab the indicator moves and the layout changes too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you have a `OnPageChangeListener` attached to your `ViewPager`

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(
            new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    mTabs.getTabAt(position).select();
                }
            });
```

Comment: I get error on override and setonpage listener,it says cannot resolve symbol

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);